# How to use NodeMailer with Apollo?

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, apollo-server

I have an React app that uses Apollo Server Express, Apollo Client and of course GraphQL. And I'm looking for a way to send some emails from my client to, for example, authenticate a user or allow a user to reset their password. But I'm having some trouble finding good reading/viewing material.

I've installed nodemailer and I've created a file in my root `server/email` folder:

```js
// sendEmail.ts

import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export const sendEmail = async () => {
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  const testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  const info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@example.com, baz@example.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>', // html body
  }, (err, info) => {
    console.log(err, info);
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
};
```

I can't call the `sendEmail` function directly from my React app because NodeMailer is a NodeJS module. I've tried importing the `sendMail.ts` in my `resolver.js` file and just add call the function in a query:

```js
// resolver.js

const {sendEmail} = require('../server/email/sendEmail');

const Query = {
  returnNotifications: async (root, args, {res, req}) => {
    sendEmail.sendEmail();
    return await returnUserNotifications(args, req);
  }
}
```

This gives the console error:

> Error: Cannot find module '../server/email/sendEmail'

I'm probably mixing up some stuff or missing a step, if anyone could point it out to me I would be very grateful.